# jQuery shows output but instantly dissapears

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a PHP application where I have to send a JavaScript variable to the same page and then use it in PHP. However when I run my code the output shows and is correct but it goes away and dissappears.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data:  { id: 1},
    success: function(result) {
        $('body').html(result);
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Some error happened. Please try again!');
    }
});
```

I accessed the posted variable via PHP post variable and the output is correct but I cant get it to stay on the screen. Is the innerHTML of my ajax.php being overwritten?

The console shows correct output also !

Comment: Does it do same thing if you pass some simple html into `$('body').html('<h2>Test</h2>')` instead of `result`?

Comment: NO, it just has the output "Test " there

Comment: Does that mean it stays there?

Comment: How are you calling this code? Is it in the `submit` handler of a form? You need to disable the default submission of the form, otherwise the page will reload.

Comment: My guess is it has nothing to do with what you showed. Are you using a button to submit a form to call it? Show more code

Comment: its being called via an on change event from a drop down

Comment: Sounds like you are loading some script that causes the after effect which is why i suggested the dummy html test

Comment: the "Test" output shows and stays there, however now when I try to access the posted variable with PHP I keep getting NAN

Comment: stop all this your complaints and post your php code. I have told you this in my answer post  before

Answer (score 0):

You are calling body attributes, try changing this line:

```
$('body').html(result);
```

To;

```
$("#myResult").html(result);
```

You can now print your response by adding this to your HTML code:

```
<div id="myResult"></div>
```

If you want to select via a Class instead:

```
$(".myResult").html(result);
```

Here, the ID selector `#` is replaced by the Class selector `.` so your `div` will now become:

```
<div class="myResult"></div>
```

Now try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data:  {id: 1},
    success: function(result) {
        // $('body').html(result);
        // $(".myResult").html(result);

         $("#myResult").html(result);
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Some error found. Please try again!');
    }
});
```

On the HTML side enter this:

```
 <div class="myResult"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing something else with your html `<body>` element? If I were you, I'd make a new element in the body and put your results there.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'ajax.php',
  data:  { id: 1},
  success: function(result) {
    $('#results').html(result);
    console.log(result);
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('Some error found. Please try again!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: now Im getting NAN value when I tried to access the id variable

Comment: I didn't change anything else in the javascript aside from the `$('#results').html(result);` line.  Can you post more code?

Comment: @dontay Do you have that id hardcoded or is it coming from something else?  If it's coming from somewhere else, can I see the code?  NAN means you're passing something that's not a number to the javascript.  Either a string or a null value would be my guess.

Comment: the id is hard coded, when I log the output to my console it the id shows the value of 1 but NaN in my html output